# Failed to instantiate one or more classes : Navigation Drawer and Render Prob

Tags: android

Error 1 :
Render Problem :
Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Error 2 :
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Error 3:
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?

NavigationDrawer activity is not loading !